# python: comparing attributes values in form before and after submit

Tags: python, validation, forms, pygtk

I fill a form fields (in pygtk) from a class instance that contains its attributes with their values.
Once the form is submitted, I get this instance updated with new values.

What is the best way to determine if the form has returned different values (ie: been modified) ? Do I have to make a copy of the object instance before updating it, or return a copy at submit time - then compare each value afterward (seems heavy to me).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have a copy of the data before and after the form has been submitted. The default `__eq__` operator will compare all attributes on of class, so you can probably use `before_form == after_form` to see if anything has changed. If you need to know what has changed then you will have to iterate over each attribute.

An alternative is to hook into the onchange events of the fields in the form and set a dirty flag if any of them are triggered.

Comment: Thanks ! An object instance copy using copy.deepcopy() for example ? (because if I have a dict inside, its reference is going to be shared, am I right ?)

Comment: I would probably go for Andrew's second suggestion: flag the fields that were changed.

Comment: @Walter: yes but what happens if it's "changed" with the same value ?

Comment: @Martin: That is why you flag the *fields* and not directly store the values. After all editing was done on the form, you update the values for all flagged fields, whether the value is actually different or not.